# How to implement a countdown clock in C++ and FLTK?

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

I create a small game using FLTK and Gui library from Programming with C++ and i want to use a countdown clock-timer. FLTK has the the Fl::add_timeout(double t,Callback) which is very useful. The thing is that i want to use that function inside my class so i can change anything inside the window when it's called. The function has to be static so i can't access the window and make the changes i want. The Gui library includes only the useful things for amatuer programmers so i can't use the function reference_to<>(). Is there any idea how can i use that function or any other way to implement this? Thanks for your time.

MY CODE:

```
#include"GUI.h"
#include<FL/Fl.h>
#include"Simple_window.h"

class Game : public Window {
   Button *b;
   //variables i need for the window
public:
   Game(Point xy,int w,int h, const string& name) : Window(xy,w,h,name) {         
      b=new Button(Point(100,100),40,20,"Button"cb_button);
      Fl::add_timeout(1.0,TIME);
   }  
   ~Game(){
      delete b;
   }
   static void cb_button(Address,Address addr){
      reference_to<Game>(addr).B();
   }
   void B(){}
   static void TIME(void *d){
      //access to the variables like this->...
      Fl::repeat_timeout(1.0,TIME); 
   }
};

int main(){
  Game win(Point(300,200),400,430,"Game");
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: You should probably edit your question to make your main points more understandable. From what I have gathered, 1. You want to use a function from the FLTK library that takes a callback function. 2. This function needs to be a static c style function to pass as a callback. 3. You aren't sure how to get access to an instance of your Game class because the function is static. The simple fix is to pass "this" as the 3rd argument to add_timeout like this: add_timeout(1.0, TIME, this); Then, in TIME(void *d), you can say static_cast<Game*>(d)->variable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't think to use the void argument like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main points here are:

1. You want to use a function (add_timeout)
2. It takes a c style callback so you are giving it a static member function.
3. You aren't sure how to access instance variables from the static method.

From the documentation here: http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/index.html, you can see the add_timeout function takes a void* as its third argument which is passed to your callback.The quick fix here would be to pass the this pointer to the add_timeout function and then cast it to a Game* to access your member variables like so:

```
#include"GUI.h"
#include<FL/Fl.h>
#include"Simple_window.h"

class Game : public Window 
{    
public:
   Game(Point xy,int w,int h, const string& name) 
          : Window(xy,w,h,name), b(nullptr)
   {         
      b = new Button(Point(100,100),40,20,"Button", cb_button);
      Fl::add_timeout(1.0, callback, (void*)this);
   }

   ~Game()
   {
       delete b;
   }

   static void cb_button(Address, Address addr)
   {
       reference_to<Game>(addr).B();
   }

   void B(){}

   static void callback(void *d)
   {
       Game* instance = static_cast<Game*>(d);
       instance->b; // access variables like this->
       Fl::repeat_timeout(1.0,TIME); 
   }

private:
    //variables you need for the window
    Button *b;
};

int main()
{
    Game win(Point(300,200),400,430,"Game");
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to select it as the answer!! Haha.

Comment: You can use the same trick to launch member functions with `pthread_create`/`_beginthreadex` ;)